# Помогите исправить пожалуйста код. Он должен выводить отсортированную табличку. Проблема в том, что табличка НЕ ​сортируется

Tags: c++

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;


struct litak {
    char tup[50];
    char reis[50];
    int vutrat;
    int kilkist;
    float serednVar;
};


void Tabl(litak *x,int y)
{
    float nomer = 1.2;
    int S1 = 0;
    int S2 = 0;
    float S3 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        x[i].serednVar = x[i].vutrat / x[i].kilkist;
        S1 += x[i].vutrat;
        S2 += x[i].kilkist;
        S3 += x[i].serednVar;
    }
    cout.setf(ios::left);
    for (int i = 0; i < 97; i++) {  
        cout << '_';
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << '|' << setw(10) << "№," << setw(15) << "Тип" << setw(15) << "Рейс"  << setw(15) << "Витрати" << setw(20) << "Кількість"  << setw(20) << "Середня" << setw(21) << '|' << endl;
    cout << '|' << setw(10) << "з/п" << setw(30) << "літака" <<  setw(15) << "на рейс" << setw(20) << "пасажирів" << setw(20) << "вартість (грн)" << setw(21) << '|' << endl;

    cout << '|';
    for (int i = 0; i < 95; i++) {
        cout << '-';
    }
    cout << '|';
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <y; i++) {
        cout << '|' << setw(10) << nomer << setw(15) << x[i].tup << setw(15) << x[i].reis;
        cout << setw(15) << x[i].vutrat << setw(20) << x[i].kilkist << setw(20) << x[i].serednVar << setw(21) << '|' << endl;
        nomer += 0.1;
    }
    cout << '|';
    for (int i = 0; i < 95; i++) {
        cout << '-';
    }
    cout << '|';
    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(11)<< '|' << setw(30) << "Разом" << setw(15) << S1 <<  setw(20) << S2 << setw(20) << S3 << '|' << endl;
    cout << '|';
    for (int i = 0; i < 95; i++) {
        cout << '_';
    }
    cout << '|';
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Виписка: " << endl;
    cout << "Середні витрати на рейс становлять: " << S1 << endl;
    cout << "Середня кількість пасажирів: " << S2 << endl;
    cout << "Середня вартість авіаперельотів(одної людини): " << S3 << endl;



}

void sortirov(litak *x, int y) {
    int V, K;
    float S;
    for (int i = 0; i < y - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y - i - 1; j++) {
            if (x[j].serednVar > x[j+1].serednVar) {
                V = x[j].vutrat;
                K = x[j].kilkist;
                S = x[j].serednVar;
                x[j].vutrat = x[j + 1].vutrat;
                x[j].kilkist = x[j + 1].kilkist;
                x[j].serednVar = x[j + 1].serednVar;
                x[j + 1].vutrat = V;
                x[j + 1].kilkist = K;
                x[j + 1].serednVar = S;
            }
        }
    }
}



int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int n;
    cout << "Ведіть кількість авіаперельотів: ";
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore();
    litak* zurnal;
    zurnal = new litak[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Ведіть тип літака: ";
        cin.getline(zurnal[i].tup, 25);
        cout << "Ведіть рейс літака: ";
        cin.getline(zurnal[i].reis, 25);
        cout << "Ведіть витрати на рейс: ";
        cin >> zurnal[i].vutrat;
        cout << "Ведіть кількість пасажирів: ";
        cin >> zurnal[i].kilkist;
        cin.ignore();
    }
    int Vutrat;
    int Kilkist;
    float SerednVar;
    sortirov(zurnal,n);
    Tabl(zurnal,n);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не ответ на вопрос, но все же. Вы можете оптимизировать сортировку, переставляя указатели, а не поля в структуре. И код будет более читабельный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы среднюю стоимость вычисляете только при выводе в `Tabl`. А сортируете раньше просто нули (или случайный мусор в памяти).

Посчитать можно сразу при вводе.

```
cout << "Ведіть кількість пасажирів: ";
cin >> zurnal[i].kilkist;

zurnal[i].serednVar = ( float ) ( zurnal[i].vutrat ) / zurnal[i].kilkist;

cin.ignore();
```

---

*Добавил `( float )` чтобы не было целочисленного деления.*